# java okhttp manually close connection issues

Tags: java, http, jvm, okhttp

When I try to use okhttp to get content from web sites, I found that I am unavailable to manually close the established sessions (using netstat to check), of course I know this is one of feature that natively support by okhttp, but in my case, the project should require to release sessions same as using HTTPURLConnection.close() methods, and I cannot find in okhttpclient.

How can I do it? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
okHttpClient.connectionPool().evictAll();
```

Comment: Oh very good! it works! and I have questions that will the action waste system resource in either CPU/Thread/Memory? because I am not so understand when every okhttpclient(s) are created, what system resources will be consume? it is java's Executor?

Comment: For that you'll need to study the code. Clearing connection pools is good but only if you never plan to reuse any connections.

Comment: That’s all of the samples. Create one OkHttpClient and reuse it.

Comment: OK, I can reuse now!